# "No user/contact ID was specified, so the Profile cannot be used in edit mode"

Tags: profile

Upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.9 with WordPress. Now the Profiles only work for a logged in user. Anyone else gets the error message shown above. It's not a members only website, so you shouldn't have to login. Here's one url: http://wiuta.org/petition

[image]

I tried deactivating all plugins but CiviCRM, but the problem persisted. I tried creating a new profile, but that didn't work either. My website is broken, please help!

Comment: Change the shortcode to `create` mode instead of `edit`, Civi expects a contact id if it's in edit mode, it would be something like `[civicrm component="profile" gid="xx" mode="create" hijack="0"]`

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so we keep Stackexchange happy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the shortcode to `create` mode instead of `edit`, Civi expects a contact id if it's in edit mode, ie a logged in user,  it would be something like `[civicrm component="profile" gid="xx" mode="create" hijack="0"]` where xx would be the profile id.